# Book recommendation in Foundational Mathematics

Tags: reference-request, logic, soft-question, set-theory, foundations

I have been navigating in this "foundational world" of mathematics for a while now ( but certainly not long enough and not deep enough ) and have read a bit about many different topics :  set theory, logic, Godel completeness and incompleteness theorems , model theory and proof theory.

I was wondering if anyone has a recommendation of a resource ( site, article, notes but mainly a book ) that gives a shallow overview of this foundational area of mathematics (Mathematical Logic) in a way to relate and show the connection between those many of the subjects i mentioned, kind of giving an introduction to each area.

I find that books of a certain topic are too specific ( and with the right reason ) and end up not providing the at least "basic" big picture of Foundational Mathematics I wish to have before delving deeper in my studies.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't know about a specific book. But I think that any book covering the basics of first-order logic, and a book covering the basics of set theory, and then some time to connect the missing dots on your own should suffice.

Comment: I suggest you two recent books : Pavel Pudlak, [Logical Foundations of Mathematics and Computational Complexity](http://www.amazon.com/Logical-Foundations-Mathematics-Computational-Complexity/dp/3319001183/ref=sr_1_1_title_1_har?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1398618609&sr=1-1) (2013) and Kenneth Kunen, [The Foundations of Mathematics](http://www.amazon.com/Foundations-Mathematics-Studies-Logic-Mathematical/dp/1904987141/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1398618451&sr=1-1&keywords=Kenneth+Kunen+The+Foundations+of+Mathematics) (2009).

Comment: I suggest also the books referenced by Peter Smith in this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/281860/books-on-the-history-of-foundations-of-mathematics) for the historical background.

Comment: Thanks for those suggestions, you two :)

Comment: One book that I've found very useful and which introduced me to this subject is "Foundations of Set Theory" by Fraenkel, Bar-Hillel and Levy. The book is not too specific and introduces different systems.

Comment: See my comments about **Introduction to the Foundations of Mathematics** by Raymond Louis Wilder in my answer at [Book about the foundation of math?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/107892/book-about-the-foundation-of-math). My suggestion might not have been what the original poster wanted in that older question, but it seems to be what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Introduction to Metamathematics" and the even more basic "Mathematical Logic" by Stephen Cole Kleene both give a very good overview of the foundational area of mathematics and provided the basic big picture for me.